# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, Remove attributes from the TAG without any specific unique input

Tags: php, dom

```
my input

<div id='makeme' class='testme'>
   <span id='whatspanID'>somthing</span>
   <p class='ptagclass'></p>
</div>

My expected output
<div>
   <span></span>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

To remove the content inside the tag, i can use below snippet, but how to remove the attributes from the tag

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find("text") as $ht) {
   $ht->innertext = "";
}
$html->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM and Xpath allows you to select text and attribute nodes.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div id='makeme' class='testme'>
   <span id='whatspanID'>somthing</span>
   <p class='ptagclass'></p>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$div = $xpath->evaluate('//div[@id="makeme"]')->item(0);
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('.//text()|@*|.//*/@*', $div);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  if ($node instanceof DOMAttr) {
    $node->parentNode->removeAttributeNode($node);
  } else {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
  }
}
echo $dom->saveHtml($div);
```

Output:

```
<div>
<span></span><p></p>
</div>
```